# Should I use "figure" or "figure out" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> At that instant the bell rang and my friends darted to class, leaving
>   me there, thinking what to do next. **It didn’t take me long to figure:**
>   if I wanted my marble back I had to venture into the forest. I had to
>   be careful, though.

Should it be *figure* or *figure out*? If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

I see subtle difference there. *Figure out something* denotes *solving* something like *puzzling out*. On the other hand *figure* (without adverbial particle 'out') is seen to mean *to understand/conceive/judge*. I searched some examples and also a dictionary.

WorldWebOnline Dictionary has a word to say about it:

> figure (v) in [sense #1, #3 or #5](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=figure)

The speaker did not take long to understand/judge the situation when left alone.

On the other hand,

[figure out (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=figure%20out)

> Find the solution to (a problem or question) or understand the meaning of - *"did you figure out the problem?"*

Answer (score 1):

I would keep *figure*. I heard it before, hence it doesn't sound wrong to me, but it's colloquial. If you *figured it out*, I'd wonder, "out of what? What is it?"

Besides:
*"I didn't take (a) long (time) to"*
Why the indirection? What is *It*? The figuring, certainly, but I don't think you should use a personal pronoun to denote an infinitive verb. Not saying the passive was entirely wrong, but I'm unsure how to transform it. Something along the way of "It didn't take a lot of my time"
*"my friends darted to class, leaving me there, thinking what to do next."*
That sentence is much more troublesome for me. What's with all the commas? It potentially means the friends where leaving while thinking. I am not sure, though.

For basic English, a teacher would probably emphasize to use a more formal style, e.g. *understand* or *hypothesize* instead of *figure*. Do you just say *figure* because you picked it up as a synonym for another word?

Going out on a limp i'd guess, it's somehow connected to *idea*, which in old greek might mean *form*, while figure also means form, so you are basically saying you idead? Whereas the meaning of *figure out* is closer to *envision*, i guess, like *produce a figure out of material*. Or maybe figure is related to numerals, so to speak as you calculated your chances, you counted your options. Anyway, the link in the other answer gives *imagine*, which is more or less suitable.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

> It didn’t take me long **to figure**:

As I read this, it is basically is the same as:

> It didn’t take me long to **learn/understand**:

Checking the definition of [figure out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/figure+out), this is basically the meaning you want. However an object (someone or something in the definitions), so you should write:

> It didn’t take me long **to figure it/that out**:

*figure* by itself does not work. If you check that definition, [figure](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/figure), you won't find the a similar definition (possibly "15. to represent mentally; imagine" ) but that is not the way I read your example.